# Node Export and VBO

Tags: views, importing-exporting

In an effort to mass export all my nodes, I installed [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) and [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). The NE project page claims that it supports VBO, but I can't seem to edit the prepackaged VBO view and add the Node Export operator. Am I missing something in terms of configuration?

I've done due diligence with searching for a potential solution, but am still looking for one.

Node Export 7.x-3.0
VBO 7.x-3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few steps to check:

- in `admin/config/content/node_export`, in `Format to use when exporting a node` check "Drupal var export"
- in `admin/structure/views`, you should have a view named "Content". Edit it, and click on "Bulk operations: Content" in the Fields zone
- in the lightbox, check `Node export (Drupal var export) (node_export_drupal_action)`

Comment: Keep in mind that VBO 7.x-3.1 doesn't include any default views anymore.

You will either want to install admin_views, or create a view yourself.

Comment: @Bojan Zivanovic : You're right, that's definitely where the problem should be ! Admin_views is the missing piece !

Comment: @bsfoo116 That did it. You're right, it was the format I had selected. I had JSON as the format, but once I chose Drupal var export, it appeared in VBO. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Even if "`Drupal var export`" is initially preselected in "node_export" configuration (`admin/config/content/node_export`), "Node export (Drupal var export)" option do not appear in "Selected Bulk operations" of view Edit interface.

Just save "node_export" settings (even if no updates made) to force Drupal variables to be saved, and `Node Export` option will appear.